# Screen goes black after a few seconds and comes back on after i press a button

Tags: 16.04

My screen keeps going black if I don't do anything after a few seconds, but if i move the mouse or press any key my screen turns on right away. I have looked in my settings and changed anything that could be causing that problem but it keeps doing it. I recently just updated it to 16.04.I have restarted my computer several times and the problem still continues.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings/Brightness & Lock, and change the "Turn screen off when inactive for:"

[image]

Go to System Settings/Power, and check the "Suspend when inactive for:"

[image]